# Show that $f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac n {n^2+k^2}$ is strictly increasing

Tags: functions, summation

I want to show that the function $f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb Q$ defined by$$f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac n {n^2+k^2}$$

is strictly increasing. Could I have a hint on how to go about this? I have tried playing around with $f(n+1)-f(n)$ but it's all so messy with the different denominators that I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: $f(n+1)-f(n)$ can be made to work, and it's kind of neat. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{n+1}{k^2+(n+1)^2}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n}{k^2+n^2}\tag1\\
&=\frac1{2n+2}+\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{n+1}{k^2+(n+1)^2}-\frac{n}{k^2+n^2}\right)\tag2\\
&=\frac1{2n+2}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n(n+1)-k^2}{\left(k^2+(n+1)^2\right)\left(k^2+n^2\right)}\tag3\\
&=\frac1{2n+2}-\frac1{n(n+1)}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1-\frac{k^2}{n(n+1)}}{\left(1+\frac{k^2}{(n+1)^2}\right)\left(1+\frac{k^2}{n^2}\right)}\tag4\\
&\gt\frac1{2n+2}-\frac1{n(n+1)}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1-\frac{k(k-1)}{n^2}}{\left(1+\frac{k^2}{n^2}\right)\left(1+\frac{(k-1)^2}{n^2}\right)}\tag5\\
&=\frac1{2n+2}-\frac1{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^n\left[\frac{\frac{k}{n}}{1+\frac{k^2}{n^2}}-\frac{\frac{k-1}{n}}{1+\frac{(k-1)^2}{n^2}}\right]\tag6\\[9pt]
&=0\tag7
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(2)$: separate the $k=n+1$ term from the left sum and combine the rest
$(3)$: algebra
$(4)$: algebra
$(5)$: $\frac{k}{n+1}\gt\frac{k-1}{n}$ and $\frac{1-xy}{\left(1+x^2\right)\left(1+y^2\right)}$ is strictly decreasing in $x$ when $x,y\in[0,1]$
$(6)$: algebra
$(7)$: telescoping series sums to $\frac12$

Comment: That was a quick downvote. I have no idea why.

Comment: You have $f(n+1) - f(n) \geq 0$. The question asks to prove that it's _strictly_ increasing. However, the downvote was not mine!

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: I have adjusted the inequalities, which were strict.

Comment: @robjohn: Upvote (+1) and not only to overcome the nonsensical downvote.

Comment: (+1) thank you!

Answer (score 3):

A nice discussion of this problem is given in *[Monotonicity of Riemann Sums](https://www.carma.newcastle.edu.au/jon/Riemannsums-talk.pdf)* by D. Borwein, J. M. Borwein and B. Sims where conditions ensuring monotonicity of right and left Riemann sums are analysed.

> - In particular according to *Corollary 3 (Monotonicity for decreasing functions with a concave symmetrization)* the following is valid:
>
>   If the function $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ is decreasing on the interval $[0,1]$ and its *symmetrization* 
>     \begin{align*}
>     F_f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left(f(x)+f(1-x)\right)
>     \end{align*}
>     is concave, then the right Riemann sum
>     \begin{align*}
>     \color{blue}{\tau_n(f)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)}
>     \end{align*}
>     increases with $n$, necessarily to $\int_0^1f$.

- The following *Example 2*: Monotonicity of $\tau_n$ for $1/(1+x^2)$ is the current problem with
  \begin{align*}
  f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}
  \end{align*}
  and
  \begin{align*}
    \color{blue}{\tau_n}&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2}\color{blue}{=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n}{n^2+k^2}}\tag{1}
    \end{align*}

Since  $f$ is decreasing in $[0,1]$ and the convexity of
\begin{align*}
F_f(x)&=\frac{1}{2}\left(f(x)+f(1-x)\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\frac{1}{1+(1-x)^2}\right)
\end{align*}
can be shown by checking the second derivative $F_f^{\prime\prime}(x)$ is negative in $[0,1]$, monotonicity of (1) follows according to Corollary 3.

Comment: (+1) This answer is more general. It would be nice to see the proof of Corollary $3$ here (I will download the pdf while the link is good).

Comment: @robjohn: Thanks for the credit. I will add the proof within the next few days.

Comment: (+1) Interesting result! I added the proof of a slight variant of Corollary 3 below. Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 2):

I will supplement **@Markus Scheuer**'s answer by providing a proof of the claim (Corollary 3 of [*Monotonicity of Riemann Sums*](https://www.carma.newcastle.edu.au/jon/Riemannsums-talk.pdf) by D. Borwein, J. M. Borwein and B. Sims) in a slightly generalized setting.

> **Lemma.** Let $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. Suppose that
>   $$F(x) = \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda) f(1-x) $$
>   is concave. If we write $\tau_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\frac{1}{n}$, then we have the following inquality
>   $$ \tau_{n+1} \geq \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}f(0) + \frac{n(n+2)}{(n+1)^2} \tau_n. \tag{*} $$

As a corollary, suppose that $f$ and $\lambda$ satisfy the assumption of Lemma. Then

- If $f(0)$ is the global maximum of $f$, then $\tau_{n+1} \geq \tau_n$ since $f(0) \geq \tau_n$.
- If $0$ is the unique maximum point of $f$, then we have strict inequality $\tau_{n+1} > \tau_n$.

---

*Proof of Lemma.* We may write

$$ \tau_{n+1} = \frac{f(1)}{n+1} + \sum_{k=1}^{n} F\left(\frac{k}{n+1}\right)\frac{1}{n+1}. $$

Now by using the identity $ \frac{k}{n+1} = \frac{k}{n+1}\left(\frac{k-1}{n}\right) + \frac{n+1-k}{n+1} \left( \frac{k}{n} \right) $ together with the concavity of $F$,

$$ F\left(\frac{k}{n+1}\right)
\geq \frac{k}{n+1} F\left(\frac{k-1}{n}\right) + \frac{n+1-k}{n+1} F\left( \frac{k}{n} \right). $$

Plugging this back, we find that

\begin{align*}
\tau_{n+1}
&\geq \frac{f(1)}{n+1} + \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left[ \frac{k}{(n+1)^2} F\left(\frac{k-1}{n}\right) + \frac{n+1-k}{(n+1)^2} F\left( \frac{k}{n} \right) \right] \\
\\
%
%
&= \frac{f(1)}{n+1} + \color{red}{\lambda \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{(n+1)^2} f\left(\frac{k-1}{n}\right)} + \color{blue}{(1-\lambda) \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{(n+1)^2} f\left(\frac{n-k+1}{n}\right)} \\
&\hspace{4.1em} + \color{blue}{\lambda \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{n+1-k}{(n+1)^2} f\left( \frac{k}{n} \right)} + \color{red}{(1-\lambda) \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{n+1-k}{(n+1)^2} f\left( \frac{n-k}{n} \right)} \\
\\
%
%
&= \frac{f(1)}{n+1} + \color{red}{\lambda \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{k+1}{(n+1)^2} f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)} + \color{blue}{(1-\lambda) \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{n+1-k}{(n+1)^2} f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)} \\
&\hspace{4.1em} + \color{blue}{\lambda \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{n+1-k}{(n+1)^2} f\left( \frac{k}{n} \right)} + \color{red}{(1-\lambda) \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{k+1}{(n+1)^2} f\left( \frac{k}{n} \right)} \\
\\
%
%
&= \frac{f(0)}{(n+1)^2} + \color{red}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{k+1}{(n+1)^2} f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)} + \color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{n+1-k}{(n+1)^2} f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)} \\
\\
%
%
&= \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}f(0) + \frac{n(n+2)}{(n+1)^2} \tau_n
\end{align*}

as desired. ////

Comment: (+1) Thanks for this proof. Is the fact that $\frac{n(n+2)}{(n+1)^2}\lt1$ a problem in applying this to the desired inequality?

Comment: @robjohn, Please correct me if I am not following your question, but my understanding is that $\frac{n(n+2)}{(n+1)^2} < 1$, or equivalently, $1-\frac{n(n+2)}{(n+1)^2} = \frac{1}{(1+n)^2} > 0$, is helping because it makes the RHS of the main inequality a convex linear combination of $f(0)$ and $S_n$. Consequently, if $f$ is also decreasing, then $f(0) \geq S_n$ and we have $S_{n+1} \geq S_n$ as required.

Comment: Okay, I missed that $f(0)\ge S_n$.

Comment: @SangchulLee: Many thanks for your contribution. (+1) This is fine team-work. :-)

Answer (score -1):

**hint**

Let $$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

$f$ is strictly  decreasing at $[0,1]$.

The sum $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{1+(\frac{k}{n})^2}$$ is a Darboux lower sum which increases when the step of the partage becomes smaller.

$$L(f,\sigma_n)<L(f,\sigma_{n+1})$$

Comment: To be clear, a lower Darboux sum increases for sure when the partition is refined. Incrementing $n$ by 1 is not always a  refinement. For example, $(0,1/3,2/3,1)$ is not a refinement of $(1,1/2,1)$. So the hint suggests lower Darboux sums for decreasing functions are always increasing for sequences of uniform partitions.  I'm not so sure.  But to prove it is more work than solving this special case.

Comment: So we'd have $f(kn) > f(n)$ for integers with $n \ge 1$ and $k \ge 2$.  (Here $f$ is the one in the original post, not the one in this answer.)  This can't be extended to give a proof that $f$ is increasing without some additional work - for example the sum-of-divisors function satisfies this inequality (as do many other functions studied in number theory), but is not increasing on the integers.